# What's the best way to get from Billund Airport to Legoland Resort Hotel?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, denmark

I'll be traveling with two young children (and carrying a suitcase or two), landing at BLL at the early evening - around 18:30 on a Saturday, after a day of flights and connections.

We will be flying back from the same airport, if that matters.

I prioritize safty, comfort and speed over cost.

Given all that, **What's the best way to get to Legoland Resort Hotel?**
Is there a shuttle? Direct bus? Should I order a taxi?

Appreciate additional details about the option you recommend (e.g. Can you buy bus tickets on the bus and if not, where? Is it better to arrange a taxi in advance or just order one after landing? Are there known scams/overpriced taxi services etc.).

Many thanks.

Comment: Which hotel are you staying at exactly? As far as I can tell, there is no hotel called “Legoland Resort Hotel” in Billund (there’s one in the UK, but that’s obviously not the one). There’s Hotel LEGOLAND, there’s LEGOLAND Castle Hotel, and there’s LEGOLAND Hotel & Conference. They’re all quite close to each other, but easiest access to each is from different roads, so which bus to take (if you go by bus) would depend on which exact hotel it is.

Comment: Comparing prices between Crazydre and Henrik’s answers: a taxi from the airport straight to the hotel will cost somewhere in the region of DKK 150–175 (going by average taxi prices). Going by bus will cost you DKK 26 per adult and DKK 13 per child; each adult can bring up to two children below age 12 for free; a paying child (below age 16) can bring one child below age 12 for free. So if you're travelling alone with two children under 12, the total cost for the bus would be DKK 26. The walk from the nearest bus stops to each of the hotels is about 100 m.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Thanks for the clarification - While their web page call it Legoland Resort Hotel - I see that in Google.maps etc. it's called just Legoland Hotel.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - also, the detail about children travelling for free is _very_ useful - if you write your own answer or suggest an edit to Crazydre's with that info, I'll make that the accepted one. That's exactly the kind of thing a tourist wouldn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Henrik says, taking a taxi would be the easiest and most comfortable solution, since you won’t have to walk or carry your luggage anywhere at all, basically. But public transportation should also be quite easy, and a fair bit cheaper, because Danish taxis are not cheap. Going by standard taxi rates, a taxi will probably set you back something like DKK 150–175 (€20–23.50, $22–26) for a three-kilometre ride that will take about four minutes.

I haven’t gone on the specific bus routes that go by Billund Airport, but Danish buses (particularly ones that pass larger airports) generally have a space set aside for prams, luggage and such things, usually on the right side of the bus between the front door (entry, next to the driver) and the middle door (often exit-only), so you don’t need to worry about having to cram your bags up on to the seat with you.

Google Maps is actually quite accurate when it comes to public transit in Denmark – it pulls data from the same sources as the purely Danish site [Rejseplanen](https://rejseplanen.dk), so the results are usually the same.

Looking at your specific time and the clarification as to which exact hotel you’re staying at, [this Google Maps direction guide](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Billund+Airport,+Passagerterminalen,+Billund/Hotel+Legoland,+%C3%85stvej+10,+7190+Billund/@55.7411612,9.1266716,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x464b711ae13749fb:0xb8f581d4347e0f63!2m2!1d9.1480728!2d55.7461876!1m5!1m1!1s0x464b717428bfa99b:0x11ea0c0688b346cd!2m2!1d9.1276162!2d55.7335058!2m3!6e0!7e2!8j1691865000!3e3) shows that you can take buses **43, 143 or 166** – they all stop at a bus stop very usefully named *Åstvej v. Hotel Legoland* (‘Åst Road by Hotel Legoland’), from where it’s about a 200-metre walk to the hotel itself (Google Maps says to follow the road, then turn left, then left again, but you can cut across the parking lot, that’s quicker).

Åstvej is the **second stop** from the airport on all three lines (the first stop is the main entrance to LEGOLAND and Lalandia), but you should keep a lookout, since buses won’t stop if there are no passengers waiting by the bus stop and no one has pressed the ‘Stop’ button on the bus. The bus journey itself takes about five minutes. To be on the safe side, you can tell the driver that’s where you’re going, and they’ll usually make sure to stop and announce it when you get there. ‘Åstvej’ is pronounced [ˈɔːˀstvaɪ̯ˀ], in an English-based phonetic respelling approximately *oast-vye*, but if you just say the hotel name, the driver will probably know which stop you mean.

The company operating the buses is [Sydtrafik](https://sydtrafik.dk/en/), who have an English version of their website with more details. You can buy the ticket on the bus, but they only take cash (no cards) in Danish kroner or Euros, and you can only expect change up to the nearest hundred kroner. They also have an app available [in Apple’s app store](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1202269337) and [in Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.sydtrafik.mobilbillet) (both in English); you can use a payment card to buy the ticket ahead of time in the app if you prefer.

The price for a single adult (age 16+) ticket is DKK 26 (€3.50, $3.80); a child (age < 16) ticket is half price. One adult traveller can bring up to two children under 12 on their ticket for free, while a paying child (age 12–15) can bring one child under 12 on their ticket for free. So if you are travelling alone with two children under the age of 12, you would only need to buy one adult ticket for yourself, and the kids can travel on that for free.

Comment: @crazydre I rolled back your edit, because it directly contradicts what the Sydtrafik website says: “The bus driver only accepts Danish Kroner and can only provide change up to the nearest 100 kr.”. There are some websites, like visitvejle.dk, which claim that you can use euro notes (but not coins), but will get change in Danish kroner, but I’d prefer to err on the side of caution and go with the official company word here.

Comment: I know first-hand (multiple trips in 2023) EUR is fine (costs EUR 10 to Vejle for instance)

Comment: One minor addition - during summer, there's also a free shuttle bus going this route.

Comment: @G0BLiN Ah, even better – free is always good!

Answer (score 10):

There are local buses 43 and 143 from the airport (direction "Billund Centret"), and you buy the ticket 1) by card at the "Rejsekort" machine inside the terminal next to the exit or 2) onboard in cash (DKK or EUR)

Answer (score 7):

It's a little above 3 km (and mostly because you have to go around the airport  (the terminal is on the north side of the airport, and Legoland is to the south of it, so taking a taxi won't cost you a lot of money, and with two young children and some luggage I think the comfort of that makes it an almost obvious choice.

The issue is if there are any taxis waiting for passengers at the airport saturday evening. I suspect there might not be (it's probably not the busiest time at the airport, and there might be more trips to get in central Billund. So you might have to either order one yourself (I have no idea how easy that is in a foreign country), or find someone willing to help you (I don't know if any service functions in the airport are manned at that time). That is of course not an issue if you arrange one in advance (and I suppose the taxi company will have experience in how long it takes to get through customs (and what to do if you get held up there), so that might be the better solution. It's been more than 10 years since I had any experience with taxis in Billund,  but from a very quick look, it looks like Billund Taxa is now part of Dantaxi which would be my general suggestion anywhere in Denmark (because they offer the fastest response times where I live), so try to contact them.

As @Crazydre mentions in their answer there are buses, and rejseplanen (danish travel planner) suggests that you can also use 119, 144 and 166.

Comment: Given the list of taxi companies on Billund Airport's page and the town's status as a major tourist destination, I would be astonished if there were no cabs waiting: https://www.bll.dk/en/parking-and-transport/to-and-from-the-airport/taxa-og-limousine-service/

Comment: @lambshaanxy My experience with smaller airports in Scandinavia has been that *assuming* a taxi will be there to just haul is indeed not always correct. I would at least save the number of a cab company in advance if that's how you want to travel.

Comment: When I flew from Billund early this year our return flight was delayed and arrived at 10pm on a Sunday. If there were Taxis waiting at the airport at that time, I suspect that 6.30pm on a Saturday will be fine. That is, of course, no reason not to prepare for other outcomes :)